# Jetpack Compose Material 3 Can't find rememberDismissState

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I have changed Material dependency from Material to Material 3, but I can't import androidx.compose.material3.rememberDismissState
as the google docs [material 3 components](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#components) say
Anyone has a an idea for why it's not importing ?

Solved : it turned out it's in version 1.1.0 which is not yet stable so, i will use version 1.1.0-rc01 in the time being.

Comment: What version of `androidx.compose.material3:material3` are you using?

Comment: I was using Compose BOM 2023.03.00 version , then i tried latest stable version 1.0.1, it turned out it's in version 1.1.0 which is not yet stable

Answer (score 4):

In version 1.2.0-beta02 SwipeToDismissState, rememberSwipeToDismiss and SwipeToDismissValue has been renamed (https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-material3).

Now you need to use rememberSwipeToDismissBoxState.