Jetpack compose - Unresolved reference: rememberDismissState in material3 api
I want to use SwipeToDismiss() api in my code. For that i am using rememberDismissState() for storing the state but it is not working. It is saying "Unresolved reference: rememberDismissState".
Can anyone tell me the solution for this.?
Below is the complete code -
import androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedVisibility
import androidx.compose.animation.EnterTransition
import androidx.compose.animation.ExitTransition
import androidx.compose.animation.expandVertically
import androidx.compose.animation.shrinkVertically
import androidx.compose.material3.DismissDirection
import androidx.compose.material3.ExperimentalMaterial3Api
import androidx.compose.material3.SwipeToDismiss
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalDensity
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun SwipeToDisMissItem(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    directions: Set<DismissDirection> = setOf(DismissDirection.EndToStart),
    enter: EnterTransition = expandVertically(),
    exit: ExitTransition = shrinkVertically(),
    background: @Composable (offset: Dp) -> Unit,
    content: @Composable (isDismissed: Boolean) -> Unit
) {
    val dismissState = rememberDismissState()
    val isDismissed = dismissState.isDismissed(DismissDirection.EndToStart)
    val offset = with(LocalDensity.current) { dismissState.progress.toDp() }

    AnimatedVisibility(
        visible = !isDismissed,
        modifier = modifier,
        enter = enter,
        exit = exit
    ) {
        SwipeToDismiss(
            state = dismissState,
            background = { background(offset) },
            dismissContent = { content(isDismissed) })
    }


}


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76050423/jetpack-compose-material-3-cant-find-rememberdismissstate

Try to add this line to the SwipeToDisMissItem() function.
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class, ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)

Please verify that the correct Material dependency has been installed and ensure the material dependency is accurate.
implementation('androidx.compose.material:$currentLatestVersion')

